# How to get the route group prefix when using RouteGroupBuilder in ASP.NET Core 7 WebApi

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

The .NET v7 framework introduced the concept of Route Groups to group mapped endpoints together based on a common prefix in the path:

```cs
app.MapGroup("/public/todos").MapTodosApi();
```

Now, in order to return an absolute path for the `Created` response (i.e. to a `POST` request), I need that route path prefix inside the service. This usecase is even discussed [in the official documentation](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/asp-net-core-updates-in-dotnet-7-preview-4/#route-groups):

> Instead of using relative addresses for the Location header in the 201 Created result, it’s also possible to use GroupRouteBuilder.GroupPrefix to construct a root-relative address

However, the `GroupRouteBuilder` class does not exist. There is only a [`RouteGroupBuilder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.routing.routegroupbuilder?view=aspnetcore-7.0), but an instance of it has no member `GroupPrefix`. Any suggestions how to actually get the prefix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That [document](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/asp-net-core-updates-in-dotnet-7-preview-4/#route-groups) you linked - although being a preview one - mentions:

> use `GetPathByRouteValues` or `GetUriByRouteValues` with a `routeName` for even more options.

The offical one about link generation is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/minimal-apis?view=aspnetcore-7.0#named-endpoints-and-link-generation).
It shows how to inject and use a [LinkGenerator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.routing.linkgenerator) (*which also contains above 2 mentioned methods*) in combination with such a named route.

> Endpoints can be given names in order to generate URLs to the endpoint. Using a named endpoint avoids having to hard code paths in an app

To apply this to the example you are referring to;
give a name to the route that retrieves a `Todo` item,
and use that one when generating the created-at url.

---

```
var group = app.MapGroup("todos");
group
    .MapGet("/{id}", (int id) =>
    {                
        // ...
        return new Todo { Id = id };
    })
    .WithName("GetToDo");

group
    .MapPost("/", (Todo todo, LinkGenerator linkGenerator) =>
    {
        // ...
        var url = linkGenerator.GetPathByName("GetToDo", new { id = todo.Id });
        return TypedResults.Created(url, todo);
    });
```

---

The idea about using the group prefix when composing the created-at url will not suffice in case the pattern of the GET (get-item) endpoint has an extra segment, since that one will not be included. You'll end up with combining multiple hard coded string parts.

In case the get-todo-item endpoint from above example would have an additional `extra` segment - as shown in the example below - then the created-at url for `ToDo` item with id `123` must be

```
/todos/extra/123
```

Combining `linkGenerator` with a named route takes care of that.

```
group
    .MapGet("/extra/{id}", (int id) =>
    {                
        // ...
        return new Todo { Id = id };
    })
    .WithName("GetToDo");
```

Comment: Awarding you the bounty, but the solution doesn't "feel" right to me. I would be required to assign a name to each endpoint individually. There is `WithGroupName()` to assign a name to a group, but linkGenerator.GetPathByName() will not work with a group name.

Comment: I tend to say that only the endpoints being referred to via e.g. a created-at or redirect-to will need to have a name. A group name won't work because it doesn't uniquely identify an endpoint.

Comment: `WithGroupName` adds to the endpoint MetaData for each endpoint in the group (so only once per group). You can inspect the metadata at the created endpoint, and get the GroupName/Prefix.

Answer (score 0):

I deleted my other answer as it only showed the full route pattern as you mentioned. I was able to get the Prefix by inspecting the `EndpointDataSource`s, and going backwards to the `RouteGroupBuilder` (using reflection). Still not very pretty, but if you have to do it and don't want to store it separately, this could be a temporary option.

```
app.MapGroup("/public/todos").MapTodosApi();

app.Run();

public class Todo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string? Title { get; set; }
    public bool IsComplete { get; set; }
}

public static class TodosApi
{
    public static RouteGroupBuilder MapTodosApi(this RouteGroupBuilder group)
    {
        group.MapPost("/test", CreateTodo);
        return group;
    }

    public static async Task<Created<Todo>> CreateTodo(Todo todo, IEnumerable<EndpointDataSource> endpointSources)
    {
        var compositeDataSource = (CompositeEndpointDataSource)(endpointSources.FirstOrDefault());
        var datasource = compositeDataSource.DataSources.FirstOrDefault();

        var nestedTypes = typeof(RouteGroupBuilder).GetNestedTypes(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
        var routeGroupBuilderField = nestedTypes[0].GetField("_routeGroupBuilder", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
        var routeGroupValue = routeGroupBuilderField.GetValue(datasource);
        var partialPrefixField = typeof(RouteGroupBuilder).GetField("_partialPrefix", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
        
        var partialPrefixValue = partialPrefixField.GetValue(routeGroupValue);

        
        return TypedResults.Created($"{todo.Id}", todo);
    }
}
```

`partialPrefixValue` returns "/public/todos", not the full "/public/todos/test". The `_partialPrefix` is a field in the `RouteGroupBuilder`: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/79e341268ac468cab6cfb09d6a1543103f66143c/src/Http/Routing/src/RouteGroupBuilder.cs

Answer (score -1):

in simple cases you can just define a variable like

```
const string TodoRoute = "/public/todos"
```

and then use it

```
var group = app.MapGroup(TodoRoute);
```

....

```
var createdPath = $"{TodoRoute}/{todo.Id}";
return Results.Created(createdPath, todo);
```

Comment: -1 for me as hardcoding your absolute path into your source  is a bad idea, and of course an obvious thing that doesn't require pointing out

Comment: In my opinion, this approach is no more hardcoded than this one
app.MapGroup("/public/todos").MapTodosApi();
You define the path only once. You must define it somewhere at least once anyway